# Android Camera Preview is incorrect on Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android, android-camera, rhomobile

When I load the camera in my app with a Samsung Galaxy S3 on Android 4.0.4, the preview image is just green and fuzzy with horizontal noise. The camera button looks fine. When I take the picture, the saved file looks good. I tested the build in camera app and it works just fine.

This issue does not happen on a Samsung Galaxy S and Motorola Electrify running Android 2.3.

I use Rhomobile for development. Here is a link to the Android camera source code: https://github.com/rhomobile/rhodes/tree/master/platform/android/Rhodes/src/com/rhomobile/rhodes/camera

This is what I get when I bring up the camera:
[image]

My setup:
- Samsung Galaxy S3 on Android 4.0.4
- Rhodes 3.4.2
- minSDK: 8
- Android SDK: 4.1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed this problem by changing my camera setting from:

settings = {:desired_width => 800, :desired_height => 800, :flash_mode => 'auto'}
Camera::take_picture(url_for(:action => :camera_callback_new), settings)

to

settings = {:desired_width => 1024, :desired_height => 1024, :flash_mode => 'auto'}
Camera::take_picture(url_for(:action => :camera_callback_new), settings)

Comment: is this because 800x800 is not supported?